# user grab and move an image in app iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, touch

I am trying to have a user grab and move an image in an app I am building.

I have created a UIImageView like this

```
DragView.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface DragView : UIImageView{

}

@end
```

and

```
DragView.m

#import "DragView.h"

@implementation DragView

-(void) touchesMoved:(NSSet *)set withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    CGPoint p = [[set anyObject] locationInView:self.superview];
    self.center = p;
}



@end
```

I then imported the .h file into my main View controller and assigned DragView to a UIImageView in the IB Identity Inspector.

I must be missing something because when I build and run and then touch the image it does't move.  What and I missing?

Comment: This is not related to Xcode. `UImageView` has its `userInteractionEnabled` property turned off (`NO`) by default, you have to change it to `YES` explicitly in order it to do anything useful.

Comment: Perfect. This was just the ticket thanks